# OpenERP 6.0 File Upload Size for Video

Tags: python, session, odoo, cherrypy

I am using OpenERP 6.0 and installed web_gallery module for video but i cannot upload video files more than 60MB.

I checked and changed the server.time_out and also changed cherrypy max body size & header size but still same problem occurs.

The error is coz of msg length

self.sock.sendall('%8d%s%s' % (len(msg), exception and "1" or "0", msg))

How to fix this ?

Comment: I think it would help if you copy/pasted the exact error message you see, as you mentioned a timeout exception, as well as you configuration file.

Comment: ERROR:web-services:netrpc: cannot deliver exception message to client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/senthil/Desktop/openerp-server-6.0.4/bin/service/netrpc_server.py", line 89, in run
    ts.mysend(e, exception=True, traceback=tb_s)
  File "/home/senthil/Desktop/openerp-server-6.0.4/bin/tiny_socket.py", line 64, in mysend
    self.sock.sendall('%8d%s%s' % (len(msg), exception and "1" or "0", msg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
timeout: timed out

Comment: for web config check here http://pastebin.com/7iFDbymq

Comment: I found that pblm is coz of the above error, I create an API using bottle to upload video and it uploads the file but while i try to play in OpenERP it says same error for large files smaller file works fine.